# (C programming) Creating array and allocating space (via malloc) affects another array

Tags: c, malloc

**EDIT**: I substantially changed my code to resemble the actual structure of the original code (which I can't post because I would have to write pages and pages explaining what everything is).

---

I've been struggling with this problem. I have six int arrays, `ID1`, `ID2` and `ID3`, and `array1`, `array2` and `array3`, where the names with the same indexes have the same length (`len1`, `len2` and `len3`, respectively). The idea is that I'm re-creating them in a for loop, because the length of these arrays changes inside it. I'm doing this as follows:

```
/* Before entering the loop, I define these three arrays, where 
   len1, len2 and len3 are all equal to 100. */

int i,S,len1,len2,len3;
len1=100;
len2=100;
len3=100;
int* ID1; 
int* ID2; 
int* ID3;
ID1=(int*) malloc((len1)*sizeof(int));
ID2=(int*) malloc((len2)*sizeof(int));
ID3=(int*) malloc((len3)*sizeof(int));
/* Then I fill the arrays with values from a loop which is not relevant 
   to my problem. Let's just fill them with a simple for loop: */
for(i=0;i<len1;i++){
    ID1[i]=i;
    ID2[i]=i;
    ID3[i]=i;
}
/* Now I enter a loop, in which I create 3 more arrays named array1, array2 
   and array3: */
for(S=98;S>=0;S--){
 printf("ID3[99]:%d (before)\n",ID3[99]); // 1st call to printf
 int* array1;
 int* array2;
 int* array3;
 array1=(int*) malloc((len1)*sizeof(int));
 array2=(int*) malloc((len2)*sizeof(int));
 array3=(int*) malloc((len3)*sizeof(int));
 printf("ID3[99]:%d (after)\n",ID3[99]);  // 2nd call to printf
 /* I do more stuff here. Here len1, len2 and len3 changes, so I have to 
    re-create the "ID" arrays and the ones named "array". The idea is to fill 
    the new "ID1", "ID2" and "ID3" arrays with the values of another set of 
    arrays that I filled with values from complex calculations named 
    "AnotherArray1", "AnotherArray2" and "AnotherArray3". 
    The lenghts are always > 100.*/
 free(ID1);
 free(ID2);
 free(ID3);
 free(array1);
 free(array2);
 free(array3);
 int* ID1;
 int* ID2;
 int* ID3;
 ID1=(int*) malloc((len1)*sizeof(int));
 ID2=(int*) malloc((len2)*sizeof(int));
 ID3=(int*) malloc((len3)*sizeof(int));
 for(i=0;i<len1;i++){
    ID1[i]=AnotherArray1[i];
 }
 for(i=0;i<len2;i++){
    ID2[i]=AnotherArray2[i];
 }
 for(i=0;i<len3;i++){
    ID3[i]=AnotherArray3[i];
 }
 /* Finally, I need to free the "AnotherArray" arrays, because in the loop 
    I need to create them again and do some complex calculations with the 
    "ID" arrays. */
 free(AnotherArray1);
 free(AnotherArray2);
 free(AnotherArray3); 
 printf("ID3[99]:%d (before, after starting the loop again)\n",ID3[99]); // 3rd call to printf
}
```

The problem is that when I do this, the 3rd call of the `printf` function is different from the 1st and 2nd calls (i.e., when the loop starts again, the value of ID3 in some of its elements suddenly changes!). I really don't know what's going on here...any advice? If you need more details, please let me know.

Comment: You will not find the problem here, because the problem isn't here.  You need to show more of your code.

Comment: @Néstor Show your entire code. The code you showed seems fine to me.

Comment: How `array` is declared?

Comment: Ok, I'll show the 'important parts' of the code (it is REALLY big).

Comment: On which operating system and with which compiler? If on Linux with GCC compiler,  compile with `gcc -Wall -g`, improve your code till no warnings are gven by the compiler,  then use both `valgrind` and the `gdb` debugger to debug your program.

Comment: @Néstor: Since you don't know what the problem is, how would you know which parts of your code are "important"? In addition to Basile's advice, try narrowing down the program to the smallest complete program that exhibits the problem. (You just might solve the problem yourself while doing this.)

Comment: If that's your real code, then the `array` referred to in the two `printf` statements is not the same object as the `array` declared at the end. If that code even compiles, the `printf` calls must be referring to something called `array` defined in an outer scope. Defining objects with the same name in nested scopes is legal (the inner one hides the outer one), but it's rarely a good idea. And an important note: `array`, `array1`, et al are *not* arrays. They're pointers, and after the `malloc` calls they point to the first elements of arrays.

Comment: BTW, `array1=(int*) malloc((len1)*sizeof(int));` is better written as `array1 = malloc(len1 * sizeof *array1)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm actually compiling it with GCC. I'll try valgrind and the gdb debuggers, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @KeithThompson The other parts are just (huge) functions with multiplications, divisions and stuff that would only affect my calculations and not the values of the arrays suddenly changing from one call to malloc to another or from re-starting the loop with a different value of the 'S' variable.

About your point with arrays and pointers, yeah, I know, but you get the idea, right? About your suggestion with writing malloc, thanks :-).

Comment: Can you show us a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/), something we can copy-and-paste and try for ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**/* (array is created before the loop starts) */**

printf("array[0]: %d (before)",array[0]);

printf("array[0]: %d (after)",array[0]);

**int* array;
 array=(int*) malloc((len1)*sizeof(int));**

/* Fill array with some values, and the loop begins again */

I would note that you are allocating a new chunk of memory for the array each time.  Since it is a different chunk of memory, it is likely to have different (garbage) values.  I suspect that it would be a good idea to **free(array)** before mallocing it again.

There is a code smell in there

```
len2=100;
len3=100;
int* ID1; 
int* ID2; 
int* ID3;
ID1=(int*) malloc((len1)*sizeof(int));
ID2=(int*) malloc((len2)*sizeof(int));
ID3=(int*) malloc((len3)*sizeof(int));

... 

int* ID1;
int* ID2;
int* ID3;
ID1=(int*) malloc((len1)*sizeof(int));
ID2=(int*) malloc((len2)*sizeof(int));
ID3=(int*) malloc((len3)*sizeof(int));
```

You are declaring ID1, ID2 and ID3 a second time.
That is likely to confuse the issue.
It is effectivly a second set of variables.   That may be the source of your problem.

I would note that the original allocation never gets freed.

Comment: I edited my code so it resembles the code I actually have. Thanks for you reply!

Comment: Indeed that was the problem! Erasing the (re)declaration of ID1, ID2 and ID3 all worked fine! Thank you very much! Can you explain why this was the problem? And, BTW, does this mean that the re-declarations of array1, array2 and array3 are likely to provoke the same problem? (maybe I should declare them in an if statement, just at the beggining of the loop).

Comment: (Or maybe I should declare them outside the loop).

Comment: i generally declare my pointers out side the loop, mallocate them them once, load them, process them, then free them.   Pointers and dynamic memory allocation are places that it is easy to screw up.

Comment: My general rules go like this.   If i can, i use c++, which provides some facilities that let you avoid the pointer/malloc/free pattern.   But If i have to malloc, then i have to free.  No exceptions to that rule.   Malloc can fail.   Always check the pointer and make sure it is not NULL.   If it is NULL then malloc failed, so abort.

Comment: One other thing.  Keep practicing.  Experts are experts because they have worked through a lot of mistakes.   You can be an expert too.  Just keep practicing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was in fact part of a homework in a graduate course on astrophysics which I could actually have done in Python (which is the language in which I feel more proficent) if I wanted to (just export all the numbers that where coded in C and work it out in Python). However, I wanted to practice my C skills and, as you see, I learned lot of things out of it :-).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `array` is not *created* before the loop, it is *declared* before the loop. It remains uninitialized until the assignment

```
array=(int*) malloc((len1)*sizeof(int));
```

at the very end. In the meantime, the pointer points at some location in the memory which happens to be readable. The memory is allocated to something else, though, and that something keeps changing. That's why the two printouts are different.

In general, you must not be dereferencing pointers before the first assignment; it is undefined behavior that could return junk, or could crash your program.

Comment: I edited my code so it resembles the code I actually have. I actually allocate the array before going inside the loop ;-).